# I can't unpin or remove a program from the task bar

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Recently I installed the November Update for Windows 10, but I just realized that I can't remove Sublime text from the task bar and when I right-click, no context menu is displayed.

Is there any way to remove this icon manually?

I can run the program normally but I don't have any contextual options for this icon.

[image: I can remove this]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well i found this article :

http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3151-taskbar-pinned-apps-reset-clear-windows-10-a.html

The person who asked the question on that site said it fixed the problem.
If you're not OK with running someone's .bat file then just do this at a command prompt (after you write down which pinned applications you want to re-pin later):

DEL /F /S /Q /A "%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar*"

REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband /F

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

Comment: well that worked for task band ,but the start menu item is still there

Comment: for the rest i un-installed the application

Answer (score 0):

When I tried deleting the tiles from the start menu and then restarting or shutting down, the tiles would re-appear the next time I logged on.  After deleting tiles and then signing out and then signing the user back in, the tiles were gone.